# sql/powerbi matrix averages

Tags: mysql, matrix, powerbi

i have a dataset like this : [image: it shows id of the application, its new status (it's new all the time) and null if there were no statuses before, when the status was changed and duration between last and current status change.]

I would like to create a matrix of averages in sql or power bi as it would show what was the average between each status to each status summed up for all the ids. This is how it should look like :

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of average is represented by x (or any other alpha character)? Also shouldn't new/approved be the same as approved/new?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, ill edit the photo, it should be the same average. It is the average of duration days between each status changes. So for example New/In progress sums up all the durations for all status changes from New -> In progress and gives me an average days

Comment: Please don't use images add sample source data and desired outcome as text which we can use as opposed to images which we can't And for clarity ensure your outcome is based on your sample source data.